# hmac sha-256 in perl

Tags: perl, hash, sha

What is the perl equivalent for this php code?

`$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $all , $secret);`

I tried using the below code but in vain. The values are different.

```
use Digest::SHA;
$sha = Digest::SHA->new('sha256');
$sha->add($secret);
$sha->add($all);
$digest = $sha->hexdigest;
```

Regards,
Pavan

Comment: An HMAC is different from a plain hash. Try [Digest::HMAC](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Digest-HMAC/lib/Digest/HMAC.pm).

Comment: ya. I found the answer . use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha256_hex);
   $digest=hmac_sha256_hex($all, $secret);  Thanks

Comment: Can you answer your question?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since my question was getting more views than I expected, I decided to answer it to help others with the same problem. I found the equivalent for it in PHP.

```
use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha256_hex); 
$digest=hmac_sha256_hex($all, $secret);
```

Hope it helps.